# Flask server doesn't render bokeh charts in remote

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, data-visualization, bokeh

I have the following code to run a Flask server:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, url_for, request, render_template, redirect, flash,     session
from bokeh.embed import autoload_server
from bokeh.client import pull_session

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if valid_login(request.form['username'], request.form['password']):
            flash("Succesfully logged in")
            session['username'] = request.form.get('username')
            return redirect(url_for('welcome'))
        else:
            error = 'Incorrect username and password'

    return render_template('login.html', error = error)

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

def valid_login(username, password):
    if username == password:
        return True
    else:
        return False

@app.route('/')
def welcome():
    if 'username' in session:
        return render_template('welcome.html', username = session['username'])
    else:
    return redirect(url_for('login'))

@app.route('/Gapminder')
def gapminder():
    if 'username' in session:
        sessione = pull_session(app_path = "/main")
        bokeh_script = autoload_server(None, app_path = "/main", session_id=sessione.id)
        return render_template("gapminder.html", bokeh_script = bokeh_script)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('login'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    host = os.getenv('IP', 'locahost')
    port = int(os.getenv('PORT', 5000))
    app.debug = True
    app.secret_key = '\xc9ixnRb\xe40\xd4\xa5\x7f\x03\xd0y6\x01\x1f\x96\xeao+\x8a\x9f\xe4'
    app.run(host = host, port = port)
```

I run the bokeh server chart with

```
bokeh serve main.py --allow-websocket-origin=localhost:5000 --host *
```

and the flask server with

```
python run_flask.py
```

Well, I can see the bokeh reder in my local enviroment at the address

```
localhost:5006/main
```

and also the flask web page with the bokeh chart, also rendered and working ok at
    localhost:5000

The problem is when I try to access fro another machine in the same local network. I can see the bokeh render chart at
    ip:5006/main. 
The flask web page
    ip:5000
is also ok except the bokeh renderer, I can't see it.

can you help me please? Thanks a lot.